# Why is the output not ASCII value of 1?

Tags: c, loops, ascii

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   char cnt=0;
   for(cnt;cnt>2;cnt=cnt+1);
   printf("%d",cnt);
}
```

I think that the output of code should be ASCII value of 1 because the value of 0 is incremented after the loop and what should be actual output, 0 or ASCII value of zero(as while initializing 0 is not in quotes)?

Comment: Did you mean `cnt < 2`?

Comment: No it is cnt > 2.

Comment: The action that is executed after each iteration of the loop, is never called if the condition is false already from the beginning. No iteration  => no increment

Comment: What is wrong in the condition in the begining?

Comment: The loop body (here `;`) and the incrementation (`cnt = cnt+1`) is only executed if the condition is true, which it is not.

Comment: `cnt>2` is false if you start with `cnt=0`. And the initial action is useless in your case because `cnt` is an expression without any side effect.

Comment: What should be the out put just 0 or ASCII value of 0?

Comment: @JayeshKumpawat if ou had read the chapter dealing with `printf` in your C text book, you'd know that the `%d` format specifier simpliy prints the value of the argument, so if `cnt` contains 42 `printf("%d",cnt)`  will print `42`.

Comment: As a wild guess, are you trying to write something like this: `int main(void) { for (char c = '0'; c <= '9'; ++c) { printf("char: \'%c\' ASCII: %d\n", c, (int)c); }}`?

Comment: The ASCII-encoded text representation of `0` (on ASCII-based systems), so byte 0x30.

Comment: the loop-condition is checked and false before the loop to start.

Answer (score 1):

The condition `cnt > 2` fails because the value of `cnt` is 0 which is less than `2`.

So, the third expression of the loop:

```
cnt = cnt + 1
```

will not be executed, which means `cnt` will remain at `0`.

Perhaps you meant to write `cnt < 2` ?

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop is never executed, so the instruction `cnt=cnt+1` is never reached. Which means `cnt` is still `0` when `printf` is reached.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
   char cnt=0;                         // cnt = 0
   for(cnt;cnt>2;cnt=cnt+1);           //loop is never executed cnt is still 0
   printf("%d",cnt);                   //print an int value (cnt), which means '0'
}
```

Comment: I have add some comments in the orginal code. I will explain...